# Mysqldb AttributeError: cursor

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am starting to use the mysqldb module in python and I seem to have some issues with the "standard" way of calling queries.

I understand that the standard way is to create a cursor and then use it to execute queries.

However, when I try to instanciate one, it gives me the following error :

> AttributeError: cursor

My Database class looks like :

```
class Database():

    def __init__(self):
        server = "localhost"
        login = "login"
        password = "passws"
        database = "DB"
        my_conv = { FIELD_TYPE.LONG: int }

        self.conn = MySQLdb.connection(user=login, passwd=password, db=database, host=server, conv=my_conv)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()

    def execute(self, query):
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

For now I get it working by using the query method, but I feel not using the standard will give me trouble in the future.

Any idea ?

Comment: The traceback just gives me the AttributeError. And the following warning : `D:\ProgramFiles\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py:34: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated from sets import ImmutableSet`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using wrong connection constructor.

`MySQLdb.Connection` instead of `MySQLdb.connection` should work.

Comment: Just different MySQLdb objects.

Comment: Actually now I have a problem when I try to execute an insert query. I could create my database without trouble but an insert doesn't seem to work. It gives me no error, it just does nothing. The code I use is : `format_query = "INSERT INTO Format (form_name, form_width, form_height, form_fps) VALUES ('"+name+"',"+str(width)+","+str(height)+","+str(fps)+");"
    db.execute(format_query)` with the "execute" function described previously

Comment: @Johanna Try cursor.execute('COMMIT')

Comment: FOund the answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018303/pythonmysqldb-weird-problem) . Needed a commit.

Comment: I just ran into this and had to spend some time figuring out exactly what was going on. Am I the only one who finds this an incredibly weird design decision?