# AttributeError: '_mysql.connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a program from python 2 to python 3. The MYSQL database I setup in my program had to be updated. I've ran into a problem very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755837/mysqldb-attributeerror-cursor), but I don't understand how to change my object from 'connection' to 'Connection' since there's no casting in Python

Here's my code:

```
import _mysql as mc

db = mc.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "password1234")
cursor = db.cursor()
```

It looks correct, but for some reason the connect() function is returning a 'connection' object instead of 'Connection'. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `mc.Connection(...)` ?

Comment: I tried that earlier. I get AttributeError: module '_mysql' has no attribute 'Connection'

Comment: There are several different MySQL libraries for Python. Which one are you using?

Comment: mysqlclient (1.3.7). Do you have a recommendation for a different one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [**mysqlclient**](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/cddc375bbec62fc79e5d354b7095b752830388b0/samples/waiter_gevent.py#L5)

```
import MySQLdb
```

**Do not** use `_mysql` as it is [low level interface and does not include all the methods](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#mysql)

Comment: That's actually what I had originally when I was working with python 2, but I got ImportError: No module named 'mysql'

EDIT: posted before you added the mysqlclient part.  Now it works. Thank you!

Comment: I would think it is a documentation design error if `_mysql` is mentioned right at the beginning of MySQLdb User’s Guide, and the first code examples use it.